# Select a conversation between exact users (by users IDs)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-performance

I'm woking on a simple chat app. It should allow users to run conversations user-to-user or in groups (multiple users). So here are my tables:

```
table users
ID   | username      | ...

table conversations
ID   | ...

table conversations_users
ID   | user_id       | conversation_id
```

Let's say I pick a few users, ids 11, 22 and 33 and want to check, whether a conversation between **these exact users** (two, three or more) already exists in database. I could achieve this with multiple queries and some backend operations, but I'm pretty sure this would impact performance a lot.

Is it even possible with one single query?

---

Side question: if there is a simple solution, will it still be effective for really long tables (e.g. 1.000.000 conversations, ~3.000.000 rows in conversations_users) and multiple-users queries (*let's check whether a conversation between there 100 users exist*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say:

> ...whether a conversation between these exact users...

I undersatand that you want in that conversation only these users and nobody else. 
In this case just a simple:

```
sum(case when user_id in (11, 22, 33) then 1 else 0 end) = 3
```

does not give the correct result, because it would return all `conversation_id`s where these 3 users participate but maybe with others. 
You need to compare against `count(*)`:

```
select conversation_id
from conversation_users
group by conversation_id
having sum(user_id in (11, 22, 33)) = count(*);
```

I believe there are no duplicate `user_id`s for each `conversation_id`, so there is no need for `count(distinct user_id)`.
For the case of a conversation between these 3 users and maybe others, you can use a `where` clause:

```
select conversation_id
from conversation_users
where user_id in (11, 22, 33)
group by conversation_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is aggregation:

```
select cu.conversation_id
from conversation_users cu
group by cu.conversation_id
having sum(case when cu.user_id in (11, 22, 33) then 1 else 0 end) = 3;
```

From a performance perspective, it might be faster to do:

```
select c.*
from conversations c
where exists (select 1
                  from conversation_users cu
                  where cu.conversation_id = c.id and
                        cu.user_id = 11
                 ) and
     exists (select 1
                  from conversation_users cu
                  where cu.conversation_id = c.id and
                        cu.user_id = 22
                 ) and
     exists (select 1
                  from conversation_users cu
                  where cu.conversation_id = c.id and
                        cu.user_id = 33
                 ) and
           not exists (select 1
                  from conversation_users cu
                  where cu.conversation_id = c.id and
                        cu.user_id not in (11, 22, 33)
                 ) ;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `conversation_users(user_id)`.

As with any performance issue, you need to test on your database and your data.  The first query has pretty constant performance, regardless of the number of users.  The second will degrade as the number of users increases.

Comment: Looks lot easier than I expected! And how about performance? Is it relevant for really big tables? (I'm using only index integers in these queries of course)